# why does content of each objects stored in arrayList have same value?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist

I have a simple code storing multiple objects into ArrayList through 'for' iterator.

```
@RequestMapping("dataInsert")
public String dataInsert(String pageNum, Model model) {

    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    List<Supplier> list = new ArrayList<Supplier>();
    int number = ss.maxNum(supplier);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        supplier.setNum(number + i);
        supplier.setName("supplier" + i);
        supplier.setDel("n");
        supplier.setAddr("address" + i);

        list.add(supplier);

        System.out.println(i + " : " + supplier);   
    }

    System.out.println(list);
    int result = ss.insertList(list, supplier);

    model.addAttribute("result", result);
    model.addAttribute("pageNum", pageNum);
    return "supplier/Insert";
}
```

Console output below shows the iterated number of objects:

```
0 : Supplier [num=13, name=supplier0, tel=null, addr=address0, del=n]
1 : Supplier [num=14, name=supplier1, tel=null, addr=address1, del=n]
2 : Supplier [num=15, name=supplier2, tel=null, addr=address2, del=n]
3 : Supplier [num=16, name=supplier3, tel=null, addr=address3, del=n]
4 : Supplier [num=17, name=supplier4, tel=null, addr=address4, del=n]
```

The console output come up from:

```
System.out.println(list);
```

Outside of `for` statement which represents the `List` shows the same content for each object.

```
[Supplier [num=17, name=supplier4, tel=null, addr=address4, del=n],
Supplier [num=17, name=supplier4, tel=null, addr=address4, del=n],
Supplier [num=17, name=supplier4, tel=null, addr=address4, del=n],
Supplier [num=17, name=supplier4, tel=null, addr=address4, del=n],
Supplier [num=17, name=supplier4, tel=null, addr=address4, del=n]
]
```

What I want to do is to create a list that has objects having different values.
I guess something is wrong on the code.
I thought the `add()` method in `ArrayList` is appending parameter value to existing list object. Does anybody know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only store one `Supplier` object in your `List` (you add the same object 5 times), and you keep modifying it in your loop.

You should create a new instance for each iteration of your loop:

```
List<Supplier> list = new ArrayList<Supplier>();
int number = ss.maxNum(supplier);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    supplier.setNum(number + i);
    supplier.setName("supplier" + i);
    supplier.setDel("n");
    supplier.setAddr("address" + i);

    list.add(supplier);
    System.out.println(i + " : " + supplier);
}
```

Comment: It works :) thx

Comment: @ConnorLee you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You add to the `List` the same `Supplier` over again and again. This results that the `Supplier` setters are called repeatedly and amend each `Supplier` in the `List`. So every `Supplier` is the same as the last one.

The key is to create a new `Supplier` with each iteration and add it to the `List`:

```
List<Supplier> list = new ArrayList<Supplier>();
int number = ss.maxNum(supplier);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
    // Supplier setters
    list.add(supplier);
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks :)